# SQL Table Design Issue

Tags: mysql, database

So I am building out a set of tables in an existing database at the moment, and have run into a weird problem.

First things first, the tables in question are called ***Organizations***, ***Applications***, and ***PostOrganizationsApplicants***.

***Organizations*** is a pre-existing table that is already populated with lots of data in regards to an organization's information which has been filled out in another form on another portal. EDIT: I cannot edit this table.
 
***Applications*** is a table that records all information that a user inputs in the application form of the website. It is a new table.
***PostOrganizationsApplicants*** is basically a copy of Organizations. This is also a new table.

The process goes:
1. Go to website and choose between two different web forms, *Form A* pertains to companies who are in the **Organizations** table, and *Form B* pertains to companies who are **not** in that table.
2a. If Form A is chosen, a lot of the fields in the application will be auto-populated because of their previous submission.
2b. If Form B is chosen, the company has to start from scratch and fill out the entire application from scratch.
3. Any **Form B** applicants must go into the ***PostOrganizationsApplicants*** table.

Now I am extremely new to SQL and Database Management so I may sound pretty stupid, but when I am linking the ***Organizations*** and ***PostOrganizationsApplicants*** tables to the ***Applications*** table, FK's for the OrganizationsID column and PostOrganizationsApplicantsID columns will have lots of empty spaces.
Is this good practice? Is there a better way to structure my tables? I've been racking my brain over this and just can't figure out a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody, I think I found the most efficient way to do it inspired by all of your answers.

My solution below, in case anyone else has a similar problem...

Firstly I will make the PK of **PostOrganizationsApplicants** the FK of **Organizations** by making a "link" table.
Then I am going to add a column in **PostOrganizationsApplicants** which will take in a true/false value on whether they completed the form from the other portal or not. Then I will ask a question in the form whether they have already done the other version of the form or not. If the boolean value is true, then I will point those rows to the **Organizations** table to auto-populate the forms.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not necessarily bad practice to allow NULL values for foreign key columns.

If an instance of an entity doesn't have a relationship to an instance of another entity, then storing a NULL in the foreign key column is the normative practice.

From your description of the use case, a "Form A" `Applications` won't be associated with a row in `Organizations` or a row in `PostOrganizationsApplicants`.

---

Getting the cardinality right is what is important. How many`Organizations` can a given `Applications` be related to? Zero? One? More than One? And vice versa.

If the relationship is many-to-many, then the usual pattern is to introduce a third relationship table.

Less frequently, we will also implement a relationship table for very sparse relationships, when a relationship to another entity is an exception, rather than the rule.

---

I'm assuming that the `OrganizationsID` column you are referring to is in the `PostOrganizationsApplicants` table (which would mean that a `PostOrganizationsApplicants` can be associated with (at most) one `Organizations`.

I'm also assuming that `PostOrganizationsApplicantsID` column is in the `Applications` table, which means an instance of `Applications` can be associated with at most one `PostOrganizationsApplicants`.

Bottomline, have a "zero-or-one to many" relationship is valid, as long as that supports a suitable representation of the business model.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. The Applications table is related to Organizations as One to One and to PostOrganizationsApplicants as a One to One as well. I guess you could say crudely that PostOrganizationsApplicants is a continuation of Organizations, except that I do not have write access to the Organizations table and additional data is being captured.

Comment: It's valid for relationship to be "optional", that is, to implement a "0,1-to-many" relationship by allowing a NULL value to be stored in the foreign key column. If the relationship is mandatory, then the database can help enforce that with a NOT NULL constraint on the column.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a column to the Organizations table that indicates that the Organization is a "Post" type of organization and set it for the Form B type of applicants? - then, all your orgs are in one table - with a single property to indicate where they came from.

Comment: Ah sorry for leaving that detail out, I cannot edit columns in the ***Organizations*** table. Lemme edit that in there...

Comment: Also there are many other fields in which the Organizations table does not account for that I need in my PostOrganizationsApplicants table.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a new record to **Organizations** (I hope you can) just
create FK from **Organizations** as PK of **PostOrganizationsApplicants**. So
if  **Organizations** has corresponding record in  **PostOrganizationsApplicants** - it's "Post"!

Comment: The difference between Organizations and PostOrganizationApplicants is that Organizations houses the applicants who have already been accepted, whereas PostOrganizationsApplicants keeps record of submissions (including prospective acceptances), but not currently accepted applicants.
So I would want to avoid adding them together like that, otherwise I could just merge the tables together.

Comment: However your answer just gave me an idea for the answer. Thank you so much.